# Android keyboard immediately disappears when typing into FabricJS IText

Tags: android, jquery, html, android-softkeyboard, fabricjs

On Chrome or Opera on Android if I try and type into an IText (by tapping on it to activate editing mode and the cursor as normal) which I've added on my canvas, the system keyboard appears as expected but after about half a second disappears again, so typing isn't possible.

On the native Android browser, the keyboard appears, then switches to uppercase, then the browser address bar becomes active. If you then tap again in the IText the system keyboard switches back to lower case and you can type in the IText normally.

I'm using latest FabricJS on Android 4.1.1 on a generic tablet. My website also uses JQuery and Bootstrap.

Anyone seen this before? Any idea how to solve!? I've run out ideas...

Thanks